# Trouble with Alert View

Tags: ios, button, if-statement, uialertview

I'm having trouble with a button right now.  As it is, the user can take a picture using the camera or photo library and when it is chosen, they can then share this picture by pressing a button.  If, however, they press the share button before they choose a photo, it crashes the app.  I am curious how I can involve an activity alert, so that if the button is pressed and there is no media, it will display the alert message along with a little vibration. If they do choose a picture, then an activity sheet is presented and the user can share from this menu.  The menu works fine, but the if/else statements are flawed I know. The picture is represented by "_timeSlip."  Thanks for the help! My code is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)shareButtonPressed
{
    if (_timeSlip !=nil)
{
    // Issue vibrate
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"No Photo Chosen"
                                                   message: @"Please Select a Photo"
                                                  delegate: self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                         otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];


    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    }
    else {
    // 
    //step 1: set up path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    //step 2: get path for local file
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                  @"time.png" ];

    //UIImage *localImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SDBack.png"];

    UIImage *localImage = _timeSlip;



    REMailActivity *mailActivity = [[REMailActivity alloc] init];


    RESaveToCameraRollActivity *saveToCameraRollActivity = [[RESaveToCameraRollActivity alloc] init];
    REPrintActivity *printActivity = [[REPrintActivity alloc] init];
    RECopyActivity *copyActivity = [[RECopyActivity alloc] init];
     // Compile activities into an array, we will pass that array to
    // REActivityViewController on the next step
    //
    NSArray *activities = @[mailActivity, saveToCameraRollActivity, printActivity,copyActivity];
    // Create REActivityViewController controller and assign data source
    //
    REActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[REActivityViewController alloc]       initWithViewController:self activities:activities];
    activityViewController.userInfo = @{
                                    @"image": localImage,
                                    @"text": @"Time Slip!"
                                    };

   [activityViewController presentFromRootViewController];
}
}
```

Comment: Try changing `if (_timeslip !=nil)` to `if (_timeslip == nil)`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided code and your description, it looks like you want to show the alert/vibration if _timeslip is nil, but you are showing the alert if _timeslip is not nil. Also, the crash is most likely caused by _timeslip being nil in your "else" statement.